# R code for web scraping running at different speeds on different WiFi networks and on same computer

Tags: r, web-scraping, wifi

I'm using "readLines" in a loop to read in HTML from a website (the loop is to read the different pages displayed) on a MacBook Pro, but when I do it using my home WiFi network it runs much slower than when I run it on my university WiFi. What is the reason for this?

P. S: Occasionally, the code stops and I get the message "Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '500 Internal Server Error'

Comment: wifi might be running in a different mode, there are many factors in play here, mode n/g/b/a/ac distance from the wifi, strength of the signal.

Comment: This question is probably far above my skill level but just curious about how much slower is it? Could the slowness be related your internet speed. Maybe do an internet speed test at both local.

Comment: It's significantly slower, it takes maybe twice or three times as long to run. My home WiFi speed is 22 Mbps; I'm not sure about my office speed, though.

Comment: This certainly sounds like a network issue rather than anything having to do with R. Maybe have a look at the results of `system("ping your_target_website")` ? (Use just the domain name, not the full URL ...)